# Wi-Fi robot with Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, remote

I am planning to make a Wi-Fi controlled robot with 4 motors (for driving) and 6 servos.
The robot will also be have around 4 sensors. Simultaneously, the robot will be streaming live video to a computer and displaying the sensor outputs.

Can a single Raspberry Pi Model B handle all of this?

I also have a problem choosing the right motor controller for this project. Would the Gertboard suffice?

Comment: Mine Does :-) - Using `motion` for the cameras, and issuing command-line commands for movement *(using Python scripts)*. I am using an old Cybot base, complete with motors plus motor controller, which you can get off eBay easy, and a brilliant (but cheap) battery bought from Maplin - see [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11721/battery-power-requirments).

Answer (score 3):

> Can a single Raspberry Pi Model B handle all of this?

Yes.  It makes it easier if you know how to program in a lower level language such as C.

To make the stress levels a bit easier to manage for the Raspberry Pi, I would make sure the camera you use is the one specifically made for the Raspberry Pi (it's design is optimal for robotics).

> I also have a problem choosing the right motor controller for this
>   project. Would the Gertboard suffice?

It depends on how much your motors and servos will draw from the board.  But yes, it should suffice.

A possible alternative would be the [GertDuino](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/5308).