# Very small sized battery for RasPi Zero?

Tags: battery, pi-zero

I have an idea for an embedded system with the Pi Zero, but for this I need a very small and light weight (<40g) battery which can power this little thing for about 15 minutes.

I am aware of this question:

- [What can I use to power my Raspberry Pi Zero with rechargeable battery?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40181/5538)

But in this case even a normal 9V battery would be too heavy.  What possibilities are there for fulfilling this criteria (minimal weight, short duration)?

Comment: I realize you are looking more specifically for a *very small* battery, but this is pretty much implicit (and if you read comments on the duplicate, the OP there wanted a small battery too) -- no one is looking for "as large a battery as possible" except in the sense of capacity, which is what mostly determines physical size.  The limitations for the pi in this regard are discussed in the answers there.  There is no magical special technology just for the pi...consider the size of a laptop battery, etc.

Comment: In addition to @goldilocks comment above, this question is not only a duplicate, but off topic. Shopping recommendations are prohibited according to the help center.  If you have questions about a specific device in regards to compatibility or how to use it, that's fine, and we'd be happy to help.

Comment: Yes, I have read that post before. I understand that there is limitations about the battery size, but I've also given a pretty low expectation of 15 minutes. My other critical point is the weight. Also the only solution there looks like it requires a voltage regulator to build with a 9v battery which is about 45g alone. I'm looking for an easy to use solution and I tough maybe there is. If there isn't then I will keep digging.

Comment: @Jacobm001 If this is true for this question then it is also true for the one this is marked as duplicate of.

Comment: I understand.  Aren't you asking a question you already know does not have an answer then?  Again, there are no secret or obscure super-light weight battery technologies around beyond what is already in your cell phone, which is what is in a normal battery pack (and investigating this possibility is probably better done elsewhere).  You know what the pi requires, you know what batteries are generally available and what their characteristics are including weight.  I'd check out watch and remote control batteries (the ones the size of a quarter or a dime).

Comment: ...Beyond that, while we don't have ["Hail mary pass"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_Mary_pass) as a close reason, there's various other that apply here and no reason to leave this open.  *Please recognize that this is intended to save you wasting time and effort here as much as anyone else.*

Comment: Okay, so I could use an RC battery (don't know the capacity yet but I guess I will find the right one) and a converter (found this [link](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10255) ). Thanks. Would be nice to have an official or hail mary pass solution tho, because it is quite good to use the Zero in small embedded systems with light battery.

Comment: I just ran across this and though of you: http://ubld.it/products/wiot-board/ That's just a programmable MC and not something you could run linux on, etc., so the suitability depends on what you want to do.  Anyway, questions about it would probably be more appropriate on our sibling [Arduino site](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: WRT a "hail mary answer": I've edited this slightly and reopened it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you are going to be doing with the zero, it is hard to know if any power source will last 15 minutes.  You might want to look at [this](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2750) which only weighs 8g for 350mAh.

Comment: I'm happy to comply with the forum policies, but I just put parts together and write a little code.  I don't know enough electronics to really give any substantive advice about the OP's project.  I did want to add that if 350mAh wasn't enough power for him (if he was running a camera or something), he might want to join 2 or more of these batteries together to meet his needs.  But I didn't know if that join should be serial or in-parallel, so I left it out.  Please edit or delete my answer as you see fit.